# Pandas datetime error when reading from excel file

Tags: python, time-series, pandas, data-cleaning, excel

I am trying to read an excel file that has two columns using pandas.

This is how the data looks in excel file:

```
DT                    Values
2019-11-11 10:00      28.9
2019-11-11 10:01      56.25
2019-11-11 10:02      2.45
2019-11-11 10:03      96.3
2019-11-11 10:04      18.4
2019-11-11 10:05      78.9
```

This is how it looks when I read using pandas:

```
DT                         Values
2019-11-11 10:00:00.000    28.9
2019-11-11 10:01:00.000    56.25
2019-11-11 10:01:59:995    2.45
2019-11-11 10:02:59:995    96.3
2019-11-11 10:03:59:995    18.4
2019-11-11 10:04:59:995    78.9
```

I have tried creating a new DateTime column, putting the data in a new excel file, converting the DT column to DateTime format in both pandas and excel. Nothing has worked yet!

Why does this happen?

EDIT - 1

I already tried the following code but forgot to mention the snippet,

```
df= pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', parse_dates = ['DT'])
df.head()

df['DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DT'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using pandas, first make sure you have a datetime column:

```
df['DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DT'])
```

To remove the milliseconds, a possible solution is to use [`round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.round.html) to obtain a specified frequency (in this case seconds).

```
df['DT'] = df['DT'].dt.round(freq='s')
```

Depending on the wanted final result, `ceil` (to always round up) or `floor` (always round down) could be more suitable.

Comment: The second snippet worked perfectly, Didn't know that I could round-off a datetime object. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to do this automatically for all columns using datetimes (without specifying them one by one), when doing `read_excel()`?

Answer (score 0):

Too low of rank to comment.
Could you check the data type of the 2019-11-11 10:00:00.000? Then look up how to convert type(obj) to date-time format.
Maybe this will help  [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)